# Help interpreting DBCC CHECKDB output related to Torn Pages

Tags: sql-server, dbcc

I've been asked to look at a SQL 2005 database that is reporting 'torn page' errors.

I can look up the MsgIDs and so on, but I just need a few pointers interpreting the DBCC CHECKDB output in a more general sense.

In this sample:

```
Msg 8909, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 0, index ID -1, partition ID 0, alloc unit ID 8795506764168298496 (type Unknown), page ID (1:106887) contains an incorrect page ID in its page header. The PageId in the page header = (1041:-523272204).
Msg 8939, Level 16, State 98, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 0, index ID -1, partition ID 0, alloc unit ID 8971733407675449344 (type Unknown), page (0:0). Test (IS_OFF (BUF_IOERR, pBUF->bstat)) failed. Values are 62916617 and -4.
CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 37 consistency errors not associated with any single object.
```

... apparently the errors are not related to any single object (note that ObjectID and IndexID dont have proper values). What does that mean exactly? If its not a single object then what is it?

In this sample:

```
Msg 8939, Level 16, State 98, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 69575286, index ID 1, partition ID 286034662653952, alloc unit ID 286034662653952 (type In-row data), page (1:207727). Test (IS_OFF (BUF_IOERR, pBUF->bstat)) failed. Values are 62916617 and -1.
Msg 8964, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 69575286, index ID 1, partition ID 286034662653952, alloc unit ID 71780678747160576 (type LOB data). The off-row data node at page (1:443), slot 26, text ID 1509706039296 is not referenced.
```

... is it referring to pages that contain data, or pages that contain indexes? It mentions off-row data but it also gives and Index ID. What do Index ID values 0 and 1 signify?

This is to help out a charity, by the way, so any help greatly appreciated. Thanks.

PS: I'm not on site yet, just looking through the dbcc logs they sent me, so I can't do any tinkering yet.

Edit: Its SQL 2005 v 9.0.3042

Edit: Lets say, you know, hypothetically, that restoring backups might not be an option because the torn pages have been in the database for a couple of months, due to a third party not putting the maintenance plans back in place after a server switch, or some such scenario. Hence assume that investigating the errors and trying to fix them or isolate them is the only course of action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Paul Randall](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/category/CHECKDB-From-Every-Angle.aspx) has pretty much every answer you'll ever need.

However, in practice, you should be thinking "restore" already...

Comment: YOu're welcome. I should have added: if you can't restore, read is "repair myths" article...

Answer (score 1):

I speak from experience here...

There error means that your database is damaged.

I would restore the latest backup you have that doesn't have this error, and use it.

You can run DBCC to repair the damage, but there's a fair chance you'll lose data.  I don't recommend doing this though, because the 'restore/repair' might seem to work but doesn't.